# Running a Python script in a WindRiver Development Shell (Windows XP)

Tags: python

I have no problem running a python script in a WindRiver Development Shell. I simply invoke the shell and type in the name of the script.  However, I would like to be able to invoke the script from a normal command prompt window.  This requires that I do the following to call the Development Shell:

shellCommandText = "C:\WindRiver_GPP6.9\wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.9"

myProcess = os.system(shellCommandText)

print "HI"  #test code

Unfortuantely, this apparently forks another process and the script waits forever for the process to return.  In other words, HI is never printed.  Is there a way in Python to run the script that follows (the print "HI") within the shell that is invoked by the wrenv command?

Answer (score 0):

If `wrenv.exe` actually does return (and I understand that is mostly sets up some enviromment variables),  why not put both commands in a batch file:

```
C:\WindRiver_GPP6.9\wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.9
C:\Python27\python.exe path\to\pythonscript
```

(Adjust for your Python installation if necessary)